# Twilio response object undefined but no errors?

Tags: javascript, meteor, twilio

I am working on an implementation of Twilio in a basic meteor app. I have set up client-side code to call the server-side method below (in this case, on login).

The method is called without issue and no error is produced in the server logs. However if I log out my response data, it is undefined. Is this a timing issue? My impression was that the function containing the response or error is called when a response is received.

Any input would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
Meteor.methods({
twilioTest:function () {

console.log("Twilio Test Called!");

    ACCOUNT_SID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    AUTH_TOKEN = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    twilio = Twilio(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
    twilio.sendSms({
        to:'+xxx-xxx-xxxx', // Any number Twilio can deliver to
        from: '+xxx-xxx-xxxx', // A number you bought from Twilio and can use for outbound communication
        body: 'Greetings!' // body of the SMS message
    },function(err, responseData) { //this function is executed when a response is received from Twilio
        console.log(responseData); // log out response object
        if (!err) { // "err" is an error received during the request, if any
            // "responseData" is a JavaScript object containing data received from Twilio.
            // A sample response from sending an SMS message is here (click "JSON" to see how the data appears in JavaScript):
            // http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-sms#example-1
            console.log(responseData.from); // outputs outbound number
            console.log(responseData.body); // outputs message body
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Looks to me like `responseData` is only defined if there is no error.  I'd try logging `err`.

Comment: Brilliant, that showed me the issue and allowed me to resolve my error! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John Hascall pointed out, I should have been logging out the error object instead of the [response object](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response). This revealed that my target phone number was invalid and allowed me to correct the issue.